# I created checkbox and button dynamic in adapter, when i click checkbox i need to change Text Color in button. But i can't refresh the view

Tags: android

I created checkbox and button dynamic in adapter, when i click checkbox i need to change Text Color in button. But i can't refresh the view when i click checkbox. I used notifyDataSetChanged() but is not work.

[image]

CheckBox checkBoxstatus = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxEnabeDisable);

final Button btn = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.buttonCategory);

```
btn.setText(c.getName());
btn.setTag(c.getId());

btn.setEnabled(status);
checkBoxstatus.setChecked(status);
checkBoxstatus.setTag(c.getId());

if (status==false)
{
    btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#616161"));
}

checkBoxstatus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        Category c = new Category();
        c.setId(buttonView.getTag().toString());
        c.setSelected(isChecked);

        btn.setEnabled(isChecked);return;
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if (status==false)
{
    btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#616161"));
}
```

needs to be inside your `OnCheckedChangeListener()`